# Consider a circle ( − 40) 2 + ( − 40) 2 = 400. Rotate it along X- axis counter clockwise 30 degree & translate it along Z- axis for +20 units

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

Write a PYOpenGL code for this operation.

I am able to draw the circle but my code for rotating and translating is not working. The code is executing but not giving the correct result. Help me with the rotation and translation part of the question.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from math import * 


def circle():
    posx, posy = 40,40
    sides = 80    
    radius = 20   
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)    
    for i in range(100):    
        cosine= radius * cos(i*2*pi/sides) + posx    
        sine  = radius * sin(i*2*pi/sides) + posy    
        glVertex2f(cosine,sine)   
        
    glEnd()
    
    

def iterate():
    glViewport(0, 0, 3000, 3000)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    
  #  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
  #  glLoadIdentity()
  #  glTranslatef(0, 0, -3)
  #  glRotatef(50, 1, 0, 0)
  #  glRotatef(70, 0, 1, 0)
    
    glOrtho(0.0, 500, 0.0, 500, 0.0, 1.0)
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

def showScreen():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    iterate()
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 3.0)
    circle()
    glutSwapBuffers()

glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)
glutInitWindowSize(400, 400)
glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200)
wind = glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Coding Practice")
glutDisplayFunc(showScreen)
glutIdleFunc(showScreen)
glutMainLoop()
```

Comment: I don't know which is your desired result. I just give you two advices: **a)** All rotations (glrotatef) are around an axis that goes through the origin. This means that rotating an object about -say- its own center means translate to that center, then rotate then translate back. **b)** Orders of transformations matters! It's not the same first translate and then rotate than first rotate and then translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you transalte the circle along the z axis or rotate the circle it is clipped by the near (= 0) and far plane (= 1) of the [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projectionv).

Change the distance to the near and far plane (e.g. -100 and 100):

<s>`glOrtho(0.0, 500, 0.0, 500, 0.0, 1.0)`</s>

```py
glOrtho(0.0, 500, 0.0, 500, -100, 100)
```

`iterate` function:

```py
def iterate():
    glViewport(0, 0, 3000, 3000)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0.0, 500, 0.0, 500, -100, 100)
    
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 20)
    glRotatef(30, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks man for the help. IT is working now.